# Carthage - How to import FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKLoginKit, FBSDKShareKit and Bolts with Carthage?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0, carthage

The integration via cocoapods is documented and easy, but how can i achieve the same with Carthage?

Comment: with cocoapods it's "easy" .. but it will never work, and you'll have confusion and problems forever  :)  Cocoapods was just a bad idea that will be gone in a few years. I too want to know how to carthage it.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works with Swift.

Catfile:

github "facebook/Facebook-SDK-Swift"

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is impossible because Bolts is a static library that will fail to build with Carthage (they only work with dynamic libraries). I've recently added a pull request to Bolts, but who knows how long it will take to move into the Facebook API. [Bolts and Carthage](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS/issues/152)

Comment: Bolts now supports Carthage. What's the latest on this?